# as400 CL script arithmetic gives 0

Tags: math, ibm-midrange, division, cl

I'm trying to calculate the remainder of a division with the algorithm:

```
remainder = dividend - (dividend / divisor) * divisor
```

All calculated in integers.

Example:
Get the remainder of 15 / 6.

```
1. (15 / 6) = 2
2. (2) * 6 = 12
3. 15 - 12 = 3
```

The remainder of 15/6 is indeed 3.

My problem is using this algorithm in my CL script simply returns 0 all the time. Why is that?

```
pgm
dcl var(&dividend) type(*int) value(15)
dcl var(&divisor) type(*int) value(6)
dcl var(&remainder) type(*int)

dcl var(&msg) type(*char)

/* Calculate remainder. [ed: 29Sep2016] "* &remainder" is now: "* &divisor" */ 
chgvar var(&remainder) value(&dividend - (&dividend / &divisor) * &divisor)

/* Prior to 29-Sep-2016 redaction, the above was coded as the incorrect expression: +
chgvar var(&remainder) value(&dividend - (&dividend / &divisor) * &remainder)       +
   and remains, commented-out, to preserve relevance of user-comments about the OP */

/* Cast remainder and display. */
chgvar var(&msg) value(&remainder)
sndpgmmsg msg(&msg)

endpgm
```

Compiled with:

```
crtclpgm pgm(test) srcfile(test) srcmbr(test)
```

Run:

```
call test
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: The CL Program source code shown in the OP, as of this date 24-Sep-2016, is surely not a copy\paste of what exhibited the difficulty as described; i.e. the expression on the first `CHGVAR` clearly does not match what is the stated expression for "trying to calculate" -- and the result would always be the initial value of `&dividend`, not the zero as described by the topic subject\title.

Comment: No because the values in the said expression are of type integer which should differ in the truncation of the division. At least that's what should happen in any decent programming language that is.

Comment: "No" to what? I pointed out that `remainder = dividend - (dividend / divisor) * divisor` is not the same expression as `remainder = dividend - (dividend / divisor) * remainder`; the CL source coded the latter.
Re integer division, any decent programming language offers both an integer-division operator and another division operator that does not foolishly force integer-only results with two integer operands. CL does not foolishly force integer results but then fails to provide an integer-division operator -- but CL is a robust Control Language not meant to be a *real* Programming Language.

Comment: @CRPence This is just a typo. You are right, I'm doing this because of school projects which don't allow to use other languages just for the sake of learning CL.

Comment: If this is for `learning CL`, then this is a valuable lesson. One part is that CL is **intended** as a "Control Language" rather than for general-purpose programming, though ILE CL can actually do just about all of it. And next is that intermediate results in CL remain fairly accurate with little concern over "Will it/won't it truncate in the middle of a calculation?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite interesting system behaviour. It would seem that the engine doesn't apply the integer trunking on the values in the brackets before multiplying it. So in other words the following is happening:

```
&dividend - (&dividend / &divisor) * &divisor
= 15 - (15 / 6) * 6
= 15 - 2.5 * 6
= 15 - 15
= 0
```

To fix it I did the following:

```
chgvar     var(&remainder) value(&dividend / &divisor)
chgvar     var(&remainder) value(&dividend - &remainder * &divisor)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a second problem. Since the remainder of the division by 10 is always 1 digit long, I changed the length of my &msg variable to 1: dcl var(&msg) type(*char) len(1). But when I do so, it seems to crash depending on the dividend value and it gives me the error CPF0819 which stands for variable too short to hold result. Do you know how to fix that or another way to get the result in a char variable of length 1?

Comment: Add a variable: dcl        var(&msgd) type(*dec) len(1). And then chgvar     var(&msgd) value(&remainder) and chgvar     var(&msg) value(&msgd). That should fix your issue. Please remember to accept my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Note that in 7.2, CL grew some additional built-in functions, such as %DEC and %INT.

Comment: Also, when explicitly breaking up a calculation into multiple statements, I would not recommend repurposing a variable name in such a way that it is no longer self-documenting. In this case, I would create a whole new variable for the (integer) quotient. It's not like extra variables are expensive. We're long past the era when we have to scrounge to save every byte.

Comment: I can not find the precision rules for intermediate results [e.g. for division] in the CL Programming Gd, but the compiler supports generating a so-called IRP listing from which can be determined, that an effective `*DEC (24 9)` [i.e. PKD(24,9) from the listing] is used to store the DIV result that is then used to perform the MULT. Use of the %INT() and\or %DEC() in the expression [as John Y notes may be available] could suffice to force intermediate result size to avoid multiple CHGVAR; default intermediate sizes likely try to maintain _accuracy_ for typical arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The described result is a side effect of the `/` that was coded as the division operator.  The `/` operator is not an *integer division* operator in the CL; some languages might offer the `//` as an additional division operator for that effect, or perhaps as a scalar function such as a `DIV`; though when a language offers such additional arithmetic features, they are likely also to offer a related scalar such as `MOD` or `REM` to directly obtain a remainder.

The IRP listing revealed the CL operated as if explicitly coded as having an intermediate value with non-zero scale; effectively `TYPE(*DEC) LEN(24 9)`, but the CL only allow 15 digits of precision, so I use `TYPE(*DEC) LEN(15 5)` in this example of a program that mimics the creation of the intermediate result for the division before performing the rest of the expression:

```
pgm
 dcl var(&dividend) type(*int) value(15)
 dcl var(&divisor) type(*int) value(6)
 dcl var(&remainder) type(*int)
 dcl var(&intermedP) type(*dec) len(15 5)
/* Calculate remainder. *two-step process -- mimics IRP listing; yields 0  */
chgvar var(&intermedP) value(&dividend / &divisor) /* P15,5 intermed result */
chgvar var(&remainder) value(&dividend - &intermedP             * &divisor  )
```

Because the proper result requires that the `(&dividend / &divisor)` [as part of the expression `&dividend - (&dividend / &divisor) * &divisor`] must yield an integer result, that means the intermediate result for that division operation must be forced to either the *INT type or to another numeric type with zero-scale.

And as the already-accepted answer shows, the following revision to use an integer for the intermediate result resolves the issue:

```
pgm
 dcl var(&dividend) type(*int) value(15)
 dcl var(&divisor) type(*int) value(6)
 dcl var(&remainder) type(*int)
 dcl var(&intermedI) type(*int)
 /* Calculate remainder. *two-step process; per change, correctly yields 3  */
chgvar var(&intermedI) value(&dividend / &divisor) /* *INT  intermed result */
chgvar var(&remainder) value(&dividend - &intermedI             * &divisor  )
```

Unlike what I alluded in a 24Sep comment to the OP, **there is no ability to code the following expression** to achieve the desired result in just one CHGVAR statement; the first expression fails syntax checking with msg CPD0058 "Built-in function %INT allows 1 arguments." and the second fails with msg CPD0181 "Argument for built-in function %INT not valid.". And I would expect the same effect [but I did not verify] from coding the %DEC builtin [with specification of a zero-scale; i.e. zero specified for the *decimal-places* argument]:

```
( &dividend - %int(&dividend / &divisor) * &divisor )

( &dividend - %int((&dividend / &divisor)) * &divisor )
```